# arcpy memory error while using ExportCAD_conversion

Tags: arcpy, dxf

I try to convert CSV point data to DXF CAD data. CSV file has about 270,000 points. I searched this issue and it is because ArcGIS is 32bit, and Background Processing Tool 64bit software is required to enable 64bit processing for Python. But unfortunately I have Background Processing Tool for ArcGIS 10.5, my ArcGIS version is 10.5.1. From forums, another solution is seperating csv data and then using `"APPEND_TO_EXISTING_FILES"` in `ExportCAD_conversion` tool, so I assigned csv data to a Pandas dataframe, I chunked it to 5 dataframes and I converted 5 dataframes to csv. And I used the export tool within a function:

```
def export_DXF(csv_path):
    dxf_folder = "..\\Outputs\\DXF"
    dxf_path = "..\\Outputs\\DXF\\switch.DXF"
    gdb_path = "output_data.gdb"
    point_feature_class_dir = "\\switch"
    point_feature_class = "switch"
    if not os.path.exists(dxf_folder):
        os.makedirs(dxf_folder)
    spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(get_input() + '\ELE_DD_SEPARATOR_POINT').spatialReference
    featureclass_path = 'output_data.gdb\\switch'
    directory_gdb = os.getcwd()
    print("Koordinat sistemi: ", spatial_ref.Name)
    if arcpy.Exists(gdb_path):
        arcpy.Delete_management(gdb_path)
        print ("gdb path has been deleted.")
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(directory_gdb, gdb_path)
    if arcpy.Exists(featureclass_path):
        arcpy.Delete_management(featureclass_path)
    arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(csv_path, 'Point_X', 'Point_Y', featureclass_path, spatial_ref, '#')
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(featureclass_path, gdb_path, point_feature_class)
    print ("CSV tablosundan Feature Class olusturma islemi tamamlandi.")
    arcpy.ExportCAD_conversion(gdb_path + point_feature_class_dir, 'DXF_R2013', dxf_path,
                               'Ignore_Filenames_in_Tables', 'APPEND_TO_EXISTING_FILES', '#')
    dosya_sil(csv_path)
    dosya_sil(dxf_path + ".xml")
    print "dxf dosya donusumu tamamlandi."
```

in a function within for loop:

```
a=0
path_array = [switch1.csv, switch2.csv, switch3.csv, switch4.csv, switch5.csv]
for i in path_array:
    a = a + 1
    csv_path=("..\\Outputs\\" + i)
    export_DXF(csv_path,a)
```

However, when I run the script, first it creates one DXF and file size is 90MB, in second loop it appends second DXF, the file size is 180MB and then it waits for a long time without any output. Is there any solution exporting huge CSV file to DXF?

Comment: In GIS, 270k points is not that much. Maybe there are limitations in CAD-files, I dont know. Does it work when you try it manually?

Comment: I didn't try to export manually but I had more points than this and I exported them with QGIS before. Also I think dxf can export million of points because AutoCAD supports point clouds.

Comment: If you have the wrong software installed, you should correct that before attempting anything else.

Comment: Now I found the correct software.

Answer (score 1):

I found installation of Background Processing Tool 64bit software for ArcGIS 10.5.1 software after setting up, and tried again, it worked.

Comment: It's great that you got it working but beware of background geoprocessing, it's a good idea in concept *sometimes* but is known to be slightly unstable, I find it best to turn it off; I had a bad experience running a process that was expected to run for a long weekend and it produced no output in the end, no errors, the code was correct, the *results tab* said it ran successfully but the output *simply did not exist*, after this I turned off background geoprocessing and the code ran fine and produced correct output... this is indicative of the unreliability of background geoprocessing.

Comment: Yes I also thought this can make the processing unstable, and it can conflict 32 bit modules. I searched for a long time to solve the problem. Unfortunately I couldn't find any solution, I had to install Background Processing. Now it works like 32 bit version but the only difference it makes the script use more RAM. I also found another way using GDAL/OGR lib that can convert CSV to DXF however the output doesn't have attribute table.